# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

First of all I know that lot of questions have been asked about this, but I really tried to find out what's the problem, but nothing helped me.
I'm working with C#, ASP.NET, Javascript, AJAX and trying to use an API to get some informations, but I get this error every time. When I tried with different API, works perfect. The API status is active, but response failed every time.

Error is looking like:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BMCp.png)

I added permissions in config file:

```
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
```

but this didn't help me. What should I do now? I'm trying this for hours, and the same result.

Tried do add jsonp and crossDomain in ajax call, but this didn't help me too.

```
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

        crossDomain : true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: url + id,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        success: function (valid) {
            if (valid) {
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you all for every answer.

Best regards

Comment: The CORS settings and response type are down to the API - if it doesn't support third party requests or JSONP there is nothing you can do.

Comment: but when I open the link in error, i get something like this: http://imgur.com/IbGASq1     so I think that response is good.. :-/

Comment: It's due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). The request will be sent, and the browser will receive data back, however because the domains do not match the data will be blocked from access through JavaScript. This is why you can see the response data. Like I said, there is nothing you can do to change this behaviour on the client. If you need to get the data, you would be best to use a local server side proxy to make the request for you and then return the data from there back to your own JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET Web Api, try enabling cors in your http config.

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {            
        config.EnableCors();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() .......
```

i make ajax calls to such an API successfully like so..

```
            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Answer (score 0):

Also Remember to decorate your Api controller with EnableCors Attribute

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // Controller methods not shown...
}
```

read more at : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api